# Watering seedlings from bottom up, is water level from the tray a reliable indicator for water requirements?

Tags: watering, seedlings, greenhouse

As the title says, I'm watering the seedling from bottom up.
I built an IoT device which reports various greenhouse environment information.

The seedlings are growing in trays and these trays are placed in a large tray which is flooded up to a level with water.

One of the information I receive from the IoT device is the water level in the large tray.
The question is if I can use this information to improve the watering.
My concern is that the environment in the greenhouse may vary and the flooding time should be adjusted accordingly.
I receive the soil moisture information too, but the sensor might be inaccurate and I could either overwater or let the seedlings dried.

Answer (score 2):

Look up keywords: hydroponics flood and drain.

Using flood and drain system means plants neither dry out nor get waterlogged.

The system  I have watched had no sensors, just a regular cycle of brief flooding on a tray on a table in a greenhouse